# Extract part of a string from a path - Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, extract

I'm trying to extract a string between '/' and '.' of a path. For example, I have a path like "/com/testproj/part1/string.html". I need to extract "part1" from the this path, the "/com/testproject/" is always fixed. I have other paths like /com/testproj/part2/string.html, /com/testproj/part3/string.html.

- e.g.
- /com/testproj/part1/dfb/rgf/string.html - part1
- /com/testproj/part126/dfb/rgf/string.html - part126
- /com/testproj/part45/dfb/rgf/string.html - part45

Comment: You say you want to *extract a string between '/' and '.' of a path*, which for `"/com/testproj/part1/string.html"` would be `part1/string`, but you say you want just `part1`. Which is it?

Comment: @Bohemian Please find some examples of path.. /com/testproj/part1/dfb/rgf/string.html, /com/testproj/part2/dfb/rgf/string.html, /com/testproj/part3/dfb/rgf/string.html, /com/testproj/part4/dfb/rgf/string.html, /com/testproj/part14545/dfb/rgf/string.html.. For each path I need to extract path along with its number..

Comment: Is the text for which you are searching always literal `part` followed by some number?

Comment: From `/com/testproj/part4/dfb/rgf/string.html` do you need `part4` or `part4/dfg/rgf`?

Comment: From your example, part4 only, added few examples in question..

Comment: What about answering Tim's question: is the part you want always `"part"` then number(s)

Comment: yes, part is also fixed.. followed by any number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `String#replaceAll` here:

```
String input = "/com/testproj/part126/dfb/rgf/string.html";
String path = input.replaceAll(".*/(part\\d+)/.*", "$1");
System.out.println(path);
```

This prints:

```
part126
```

The strategy here is to match the entire URL path, using a regex capture group `part\\d+` to retain the component you want to extract.

If instead your actual question is how to isolate the *third* (from the left) path component, then just use `String#split`:

```
String input = "/com/testproj/part126/dfb/rgf/string.html";
String path = input.split("/")[3];
System.out.println(path);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am looking for an answer using regex.

Comment: @user3222372 My answer _is_ using regex.  Check the source code for `String#split` to see for yourself.

Comment: Above expr is not workig for this example - "/com/test-proj/part1/abc/xyz/string.html"

Comment: Your question implied (strongly, in my opinion), that you want to extract the _last_ path component.  If your input above is valid, then you also would need to give us logic for how to know where `path1` might be.

Comment: In path, "/com/testproj/" is always fixed. After that I have parts where part is followed by a number. After "part<any numver>", I can have sub folders to any level..